# Shared Collection VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, collections, shared

I need to get alot of data from my database and would like to get this when the application starts, store it in a collection and to reuse through out the application.

I tried declaring a Public Shared Collection and populate this when I start the application (in the main form). It works ok first time the collection is used, but then it is empty.

I have looked around for places where I might have written to clear it myself but can't figure anything out. Anyone have any ideas or tips?

The code is something like:

```
Public Shared m_objDocCollection As Collection(Of clDocumentation)
```

And then in the main form

```
clDocumentation.m_objDocCollection = clDocumentation.GetDocumentsFromDb()
```

Edit; sorry for not adding code. Have copied the most relevant and placed here; https://gist.github.com/2365610

Comment: If you don't show us some code we can only imagine your problem...

Answer (score 1):

It is not obvious from your code what is happening but my guess is that you are (re)initialising your collection more than once.

Do a search in your code for any places where the collection is being (re)initialised such as this:

`m_objDocCollection = New Collection(Of clDocumentation)`

and put a breakpoint on these. Then run your code and see when these are firing.

Comment: Did as you said and think I found the error, my listboxes and comboxes seems to have pointed to the same object as in the shared collections, when I clear the lists, the shared collection gets cleared as well Wasn't aware that it worked that way. Thanks for your help :)